# (AWS Lambda) "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: Object of type HTTPResponse is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I have been testing my server API via POSTMAN and the result looks like this:
[image]

My goal with the AWS Lambda is to show (in the log) whatever the json response you get from this API. My code in the lambda looks like this:

```
import json
import urllib3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    response = http.request('GET',
                        "http://106.10.54.227:9062/api/v1/weather-api",
                        retries = False)
    
    return response
```

However when I test this lambda function, I get this error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: Object of type HTTPResponse is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
}
```

What I do not understand is the fact that the response from the API is the JSON itself so I don't know why it complains it is not serializable.

Is there any way to fix this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: still getting an error: ```"errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
  "errorType": "JSONDecodeError"```

Comment: `print(response)` and check in cloudwatch lots what is the actual form of your `response` object

Comment: It says the response is null

Comment: So now you know why its failing.